Is there a more efficient way to find the least prime factor?

Assuming $Q_{k} \equiv p_{k}\text{#} + 1$, my goal is to find the least prime factor of $Q_{k}$ for each integer $k = 1 \ldots 100$ .  The Python program shown below tries using SymPy to do so, but finding a prime factor of a large integer (dozens or hundreds of decimal digits) proves to be time-consuming.  Might there be other SymPy functions, another computer algebra system, or a technique based on the way that $Q_{k}$ is defined that would be more efficient?
from sympy import sieve
from sympy.ntheory import isprime
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
def main ( ) :
  sieve._reset()
  sieve.extend_to_no ( 100 )
  primeList = sieve._list
  primorialK = 1
  for k in range(1,101) :
    currentPrime = primeList[k-1]
    primorialK *= ( currentPrime )
    Q = ( primorialK + 1 )
    print ( "Q({}) = p_{}# + 1 = {}".format(k,k,Q) )
    if isprime(Q) :
      print ( "Q({}) is prime and its least prime factor is {}.".format(k,Q) )
    else :
      print ( "Q({}) is not prime.".format(k) )
      factorint_Q = factorint ( Q )
      print ( "The prime factorization of Q({}) is ... ".format(k), end="" )
      print ( factorint_Q )
      print ( "The least prime factor of Q({}) is {}.".format(k,min(factorint_Q)) )
    print()
if __name__ == '__main__' :
  main()


Output of the above program would include, for example …
Q(5) = p_5# + 1 = 2311
Q(5) is prime and its least prime factor is 2311.

Q(6) = p_6# + 1 = 30031
Q(6) is not prime.
The prime factorization of Q(6) is ... {59: 1, 509: 1}
The least prime factor of Q(6) is 59.



You surely mean a primorial number , since a primorial prime has itself as its smallest prime factor. The answer is negative , there is no general better way than factoring. The good news is that in factordb there are partial factorization and for $n$#$+1$ , the smallest case without a known prime factor is here.

For $n$#$-1$ , the situation is even better , the smllest open example being here. Note that the displayed prime factors may not be the smallest in all cases.

Even better the cases upto $n=500$ are fully factored for both expressions , so you can look up the factors (and in particular the smallest) at least upto this limit.

I am interested to learn of factordb and also found Python project factordb-pycli.  Thank you.

Not sure where the limits of Python are because I use PARI/GP for those tasks. But factoring a 110+ digit number can be already extremely difficult if the second smallest prime factor is huge.

You can reverse the task and get some information.  For any prime $p$  you can  compute  $n\# + 1  \pmod p$  without  tears.
Let's see, a big loop on primes $p$  up to some bound.  A list of the numbers from $1$ to $100.$  For eac $p,$  calculate $n\# + 1 \pmod p,$   where $n\#$ means the product of $2 \cdot 3 \cdots p_n$   If  this is zero, prnt out $p$   and $n,$  and erase that $n$  off the list of those still needed.  If you have the facilities to do so, leave it running for a few months.
I ran one job for three years. I would load raw information that I expected to take a month. I had just the one output file for the actual valuable stuff. I had at least two output files that told me how long the program had run and how far it got. That way, whenever the job got killed due to bad luck, say a power outage, I knew to within a few days worth where to restart the job.

For a general number $n$, the fastest known way to find the smallest prime number of $n$ is to use ECM factoring.  This is fairly efficient if there exists a small factor, but can take an extremely long time if there is no small factor.
Sage has an implementation of ECM factoring: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/interfaces/sage/interfaces/ecm.html
